# Decrypting Data From Database Before Sending Response Back Node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, http, angular, node-postgres

**Update**

The actual problem I am having is placing the value back inside the response after I `decrypt` it. I just need to know how to place a value back in the `response` after I manipulate it.

**Background**

On the `node` side of my `angular2` app I am preparing to send the `response` from an `api` call made to a `postgres` database. I need to `decrypt` one of the values in the `response`. In the docs it showed to handle the `response` like this,

```
              if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    res.status(500).send();
                    return done(); // always close connection
                } else {
                    if (result.rowCount > 0) {
                        decrypt(result.rows[0].myvalue);
                        let user = result.rows[0];
                        res.send(user);
                        return done(); // always close connection
                    }
```

**Problem**

I can not figure out how to manipulate one of the values in the response before it is sent back. In this case `decrypt(user.myvalue);` or decrypt it before it is placed in `user` `decrypt(result.rows[0].myValue);`

**Example**

If you `console.log(user.myvalue);` the encrypted `myvalue` is displayed. I need to decrypt `myvalue` before it ends up in the `response`. I can `decrypt` it like this,

decrypt(result.rows[0].ssn);

**Question**

How do I `decrypt` this with `decrypt(result.myvalue);` so that it is in the user `object` that is sent back in the `response` `decrypted`?

To be honest I am confused on how this look even works.

```
if (result.rowCount > 0) { // if greater than 0? Should it not always be greater than 0:
let user = result.rows[0];
```

The response comes back just fine. I can access the data with no problem on the `node` side. I just do not get how it is looping through it when it stores it. Because the `result.rows[0];` appears to me as just one position? I guess it is just storing the whole response in that one position `[0];`??

So this outputs `myvalue`

`console.log(result.rows[0].myValue);`

So I just need to `decrypt` that value and put it back in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
result.rows[0].myvalue = decrypt(result.rows[0].myvalue);
```

It will `decrypt()` myvalue .

Comment: Yes I have no problem decrypting it. the problem is placing it back inside the response after I do/

Comment: yes it will place decrypted value in response. Try this solution